# Transfer some information to previously open form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 forms 1. `form1` and `form2` i open `form2` by button click then add some information

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = TxtNewName.Text;
        string City = TxtNewCity.Text
    }
```

I am opening form by constructor

```
   private void openForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 newform = new Form2();
        newform.Show();
    }
```

i want to transfer this `Name` and `city` variables to previously open form when i close this the two values gets updated in already open form with field same name in form1
Please help me..

Comment: Are you working on winform ? How are you calling/opening the form

Comment: yes i m working in winform

Comment: @V4Vendetta see the updated que.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define 2 public properties in your second form

```
    public string GetName { get {return TxtNewName.Text;} }
    public string GetCity { get {return TxtNewCity.Text;} }
```

After calling the second form, you can access them

```
     Form2 form2 = new Form2();
     form2.ShowDialog();

     string name = form2.GetName;
     string city = form2.GetCity;
```

**EDIT:**
...and if I want to Directly set Text Property of text box with Name and city in form1 after closing form2

```
this.Text = form2.GetName;
this.city = form2.GetCity;
```

Comment: Will this work ? how will it reach the next line `this.Text = form2.GetName;` unless you close the form

Comment: that was actually what he asked for "i want to transfer this Name and city variables to previously open form when i close this"

Comment: its works but i directly use the `Textboxname.Text` property.

Answer (score 1):

you should expose properties which holds the values in form2

```
public string Name { get { return TxtNewName.Text; } }
public string City { get { return TxtNewCity.Text; } }
```

and in

```
private void openForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   Form2 newform = new Form2(); 
   newform.ShowDialog(); 
   var city = newform.City;
   var name = newform.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to pass the values to the first form, i would recommend a parameter constructor which would get your first form.

Have properties set up required to catch the values you need to pass on `Form1`

```
Form2 newform = new Form2(this); // passing instance of Form1
newform.Show();
```

So now you have access to `Form1` and assign the required values.